# AngularJS provider

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a "MainMenuProvider" that will be shared among multiple modules' `.config()` function.

I shamelessly peeked at the ui-router source code (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/src) to get a grasp on how he manages to achieve this.

Quite obviously, my simplicistic version does not work.
Worse, it gives me a js error on startup:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.mainMenu' is not available! You either
misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you 
specify the dependencies as the second argument. 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp.mainMenu
```

This is my source code. Any ideas on what could have happened?

```
$MainMenuProvider.$inject = [];

function $MainMenuProvider() {
     var items = {};
     this.register = register;

     function register(name, definition) {

          /*jshint validthis: true */

          if (isObject(name)) {
               definition = name;
          } else {
               definition.name = name;
          }

          registerMenuItem(definition);

          return this;
     }

     function registerMenuItem(definition) {
          var name = definition.name;
          items[name] = definition;
          return definition;
     }

}

angular.module('myApp.mainMenu').provider('$mainMenu', $MainMenuProvider);
```

**EDIT**: as both calebboyd and dimirc highlighted, I was declaring the module in a non-appropriate manner.

The last line should read:

```
angular.module('myApp.mainMenu', []).provider('$mainMenu', $MainMenuProvider);
```

Note that the provider still doesn't work, since I didn't implement the $get method, but that's a completely different issue :)

Thank you all.

Comment: The error message is clear: "d3.backoffice.menu" is not available. I guess the error is unrelated to $MainMenuProvider

Comment: sorry, my bad, I fixed the error (the error actually lists myApp.mainMenu)

Comment: so do you have an `angular.module('myApp.mainMenu',[])` declaration somewhere?

Comment: well, yes, it's the last line of the code section
edit: you were right... I need to put exactly angular.module('myApp.mainMenu',[])... 

question then is: why the ui-router code **doesn't** do that?
have a look at the last 3 lines: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/common.js
173 to end.

Comment: You'll find [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/a100dea755c3c364dab9a912feb9ba03152909fd/src/common.js#L196) the declaration `angular.module('ui.router.state', ['ui.router.router', 'ui.router.util']);`

Comment: Thank you @calebboyd. I guess the problem here is that I don't actually understand very well how to setup angular components... It's time for some reading.